# Iterating a file tree with a while loop with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

New to using AutoHotKey for automation and have a question about loops in my script.

What I am trying to do is iterate through a file tree in an application, pressing down until the desired folder is reached and then selecting it. The while loop I have does not stop, even when the desired value is reached.

What I have done is send ctrl-c to copy the value of the first folder in the tree, store it in a variable, then use a while loop to compare it to what I'm looking for. If it's a match then I select that directory.

```
; parse file tree

Send, {Down 7}
Send, {Right}
Send, {Down}
Send, ^c
ClipWait
esbToCompare := % clipboard 
;MsgBox % clipboard
;MsgBox % esbContainer
esbToCompare := StrReplace(esbToCompare, "/ESB Containers/", "")
MsgBox % esbToCompare
while (esbContainer <> esbToCompare)
{   
    Send, {Down}
}
send {Enter}
```

I am expecting it to highlight each directory one by one until it gets a match and then selects that directory, however the loop just keeps going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your while-loop only includes `Send, {Down}`, it will stay stuck in that since the variables you're comparing aren't changing while it's looping. To fix it, you'll need to include the code that changes the variable(s) your comparing (`esbToCompare` and/or `esbContainer`) inside the while-loop.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/While.htm